# local server and web server behaviors

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a working code in my local server. What i'm doing on my webpage is : get numbers of vote from two different tables in my database and plot them on my html page with chartjs.

I can't figure why everything runs fine on my local server using xampp and when I upload my code on my website it's not working. Maybe it's because I have php code inside my index.php file but I can't figure why it's a problem online and not local. The error i have : GET xxxx/resultats.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
Many thanks.

Here is wy working code (local server) in my index file

```
<?php
    include_once'./includes/dbh.inc.php'; // I changed this file obviously and the communication is ok

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votespoule1;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      echo "SQL statement failed";
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $resultcountvp1 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      while ($rowvp1 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultcountvp1)) {
        $countvp1 = json_encode($rowvp1[0]);
        echo "<script>var nbvp1 = " . json_encode($countvp1) . "; </script>";
      }
    }
?>
```

And my JS code which is getting datas from above :

```
var poule = ['Poule 1'];
**var nbv1 = [nbvp1];**
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChartnbvotes");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: poule,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: nbv1,
        label: "Poule 1",
        backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      },
    ]
  },
});
```

Then I plot the graph in my index.html file :

```
<div class="wrapper mb-3 mb-lg-0">
 <canvas id="myChartnbvotes" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need a prepared statement here. There's no user input that I can see.

Comment: That's true indeed, it's for a future feature, but i don't think that this explains why I have this on chrome :
GET ...mysite/resultats.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Assuming your remote server is configured to parse .html files for PHP code? Does the same error occur with any .html file with PHP inside, please test? I assume you can upload other PHP files and they execute fine? There's no .htaccess file you've uploaded that might throw the server sideways?

Comment: Check your logs or add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to display what those errors are.

Comment: This is the only page with php code directly in it, i'm using ajax for the rest. But I tried what you said, just add some php code and it is ok. Other pages can even update database normally, so if I had a htaccess file this could not be possible no ?

Comment: See if magic happens by renaming `index.html` to `index.php`. Also, ensure that the contents of your `.htaccess` file (if you have one) are valid for your remote server. I assume you have a `.htaccess` with something like `AddHandler x-httpd-php .html` in there. That may not be work with the way Apache/PHP are set up at your remote server.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the error I get :Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result(), so it seems that you're right about the problem of prepared statement. But still, I'll have to work with this very soon so anyways I have to fixe this even in this case :)

Comment: @MarkusAO my filename is already a .php. and I don't have a .htaccess in the files i uploaded

Comment: OP: `I have php code inside my index.html`. Anyway, it looks like you don't have the MySQLi extension enabled in PHP at your remote server.

Comment: @Markus, corrected, thanks, My php version in ovh is 7.3, so this should be enabled by default i think

Comment: [The manual on `mysqli_stmt_get_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) states: *"MySQL Native Driver Only - Available only with [mysqlnd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php)*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner and Markus, I solved the problem. Indeed it was caused by my remote server. I changed my code in order to not use mysqli_stmt_get_result() as you advised.
Many thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear it was solved, cheers!